# Compare 2 strings in Java upto a delimiter

Tags: java, string, compare

String 1:

```
func1(test1)
```

String 2:

```
func1(test2)
```

I want to compare these 2 strings upto the first open braces '('.

So for the given example it should return true since the string upto '(' in both the strings is 'func1'.

Is there any way to do that without splitting?

Comment: substring will help on this case

Comment: if you really don't want to split, you can also write a loop that iterates over each char, but that does not make much sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String#substring()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) will help on this case this combined with `String#indexOf()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-)

```
String x1 = "func1(test1)";
String x2 = "func1(test1)";
String methName1 = x1.substring(0, x1.indexOf("("));
String methName2 = x2.substring(0, x2.indexOf("("));
System.out.println(methName1);
System.out.println(methName2);
System.out.println(methName1.equals(methName2));
```

Comment: I guess you can remove that 0 part from substring :) will be shorter

Comment: Hi @ANS, thanks for the comment!!  I think OP wants to compare methods names, removing the 0 part in the substring will compare the method parameters instead....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**String.matches()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method to test if the second string matches the splitted one from the first string:

```
String s1 = "func1(test1)";
String s2 = "func1(test2)";
String methName = s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf("("));
System.out.println(s2.matches(methName+ "(.*)"));
```

This is [a working **Demo**](http://ideone.com/3FOQX7).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to find every thing between any delimiters, in your case `()` and compare the results, for example :

```
String START_DEL = "\\(";   //the start delimiter
String END_DEL = "\\)";     //the end delimiter

String str1 = "func1(test1)";
String str2 = "func1(test2)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(START_DEL + "(.*?)" + END_DEL);//This mean "\\((.*?)\\)"
Matcher m1 = p.matcher(str1);
Matcher m2 = p.matcher(str2);

if (m1.find() && m2.find()) {
    System.out.println(m1.group(1).equals(m2.group(1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can compare the strings directly by replacing everything after '(' by empty string.

```
    String str1 = "func1(test1)";
    String str2 = "func1(test2)";
    System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("\\(.*", "").equals(str2.replaceAll("\\(.*", "")));
```